# Trying to understand NYC code for using common corridors as return air

Tags: hvac, building-regulations

I wanted to understand the NYC building code in this situation:

I'm in a 2 family brownstone home with a shared basement (laundry room for the 1st-floor unit and a storage room for the 2nd-floor unit, along with a shared mechanical room and shared hallway with stairwell).  The return air path for the first-floor unit uses the common stairway to the basement along with a short common hallway as a return channel to the mechanical room.  The building code says that corridors can be used for return air in certain exception cases, one of them being:

> Where located within tenant spaces of 1,000 square feet (93 m2) or less in area, use of corridors for conveying return air is permitted.

I'm not sure I understand the meaning of "tenant spaces."  Does that mean the common basement hallway and stairwell is a "tenant space", or should I read it to mean the tenant's space - meaning common areas do not count?

The hallway is exclusively for the use of both tenants, both the first floor and 2nd floor, and is only a short section which is one stairwell and about 20 feet of hallway.

Does this mean I can use a common stairwell hallway in the basement as a return air channel to the mechanical room?

Comment: Given the locale, a local lawyer's or code enforcement officer's opinion would be advisable, but I read that as "what's the square footage of your space" - so, does the 1st floor unit and laundry room add up to 999.99 square feet, or 1000.01 square feet? You may also have an issue with "stairwell is not the same thing as corridor" but again, local advice is probably needed to clarify. On further cogitation "within" may also bar this from applying, as you are moving the air out of your space, through common space.

Comment: 1st floor is close to 1000sq ft so with the corridor it might be pushing just above to like 1100sqft if we count the common space as well, i.e. 950+ stairwell plus 50 sqft 
corridor... if we count the common space it's over, but if we don't it's under 1000 sqft.  If we count the entire building it's closer to 3300 sqft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply and return air can be installed in non-fire rated corridors according to the code.

Corridors are required to be fire rated based on occupant load of the building and the occupant load is determined by the size (square footage) of the building.

Evidently your building code jurisdiction has determined two residential units with 1000 square feet or less can share a non-rated corridor.

Btw, in the new code, fire sprinklers are required in buildings with more than two units.

Answer (score 0):

This is all Maryland or random stuff, but I don't think you have a *tenet space*, you have a *dwelling*.

I think they're trying to make sure you don't use return corridors for a ten unit building where you get to smell 20 people's cooking 24h a day.

Or if it's a public space: for dinky little store fronts, it's w/e. But for a supermarket they want some real ventilation.

---

> Where located within a *dwelling unit*, the use of corridors for conveying return air shall not be prohibited.

https://up.codes/s/air-movement-in-egress-elements

---

> DWELLING. A building or portion thereof that contains not more than two dwelling units.

> [A] DWELLING UNIT. A single unit providing complete, independent living facilities for one or more persons, including permanent provisions for living, sleeping, eating, cooking and sanitation.

https://up.codes/viewer/maryland/imc-2018/chapter/2/definitions#dwelling_unit

---

> Tenant Space means a portion of a structure occupied by a single **commercial leaseholder** with its own public entrance from the exterior of the building or through a shared lobby, atrium, mall, or hallway and separated from other tenant spaces by walls.

https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/tenant-space

Comment: so does this mean that unless the return corridor is completely within the 1st floor dwelling it's not allowed?  thus the shared hallway and stairwell to the basement is considered "outside" the dwelling and not allowed?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey - According to those quotes, and only those quotes, and if I'm right about it being a dwelling, it can be any size as long as it's only 2 units. And "use of corridors for conveying return air shall [*is permitted*] ."